# Move to another view on UITableView row selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I move from the current view to another view? My current view is viewcontroller and I wanted to move another view controller. Here is my code..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:[NSBundle  mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

I am using xib file for another view.

Comment: What is SecondView? (A view controller, or ?)

Comment: second view is another UIViewController.

Comment: Why are you specifically calling initWithNibName:bundle:? (The default would be to call init which would contain something like `if(self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]) {` which would load the nib for you.

Comment: actually in second view , I have 4 label in which i have to display the values those are passing from current view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure about the nib file name and set bundle:nil

okay make sure in interface builder for your second viewcontroller, you correctly hook with the appropriate class.

please clean all targets then build and run the application.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing views and view controllers. A view controller manages a view, but it is decidedly not a view, and vice versa. If your "SecondView" is, in fact, a view controller (i.e. it inherits from UIViewController), then your code is correct as far as it goes.

Comment: yes it inherits from UIViewController but still second view does not appear.

Comment: Some things to check: Is self.navigationController nil? Is the nib name right? (Note: capitalization matters -- the iOS file system is case-sensitive.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to use a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as you're seem to be attempting, as this will let you push views onto the "stack" as required and will also automatically handle the removal of views/adding a navigational back button, etc.

That said, I'd recommend a read of the above class reference as there are some issues with your code. (You're not doing a `[secondView release];` after you add the view controller for example.) I presume that "secondView" is also a view controller, not just a view? (You push controllers onto the stack, not views.)

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- You're leaking secondView, autorelease it
- bundle can probably be nil
- What's wrong with the code?